# i want to change the values of html div using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, dynamic

Is it possible to change the values of HTML through a JavaScript-function?

Here's an example:

```
div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ConnectCommunications?fref=ts"
  data-width="450" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-small-header="false"
  data-show-posts="true"></div
```

Now I want to change `data-show-facepile` from `true` to `false` through a JavaScript `onclick`-event.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What have you tried so far? These may come handy - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_element_setattribute.asp, http://api.jquery.com/attr/

Comment: very simple, use .data() function, see my ans below

Answer (score 1):

With clean JavaScript in the browser:

`document.getElementByClassName('fb-page').setAttribute('data-show-facepile', false)`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getElementsByClassName) for more information on that. It can be smart to give the element an `id`, and then use `document.getElementById()` instead.

Now, if you have a button `<button id="clickme"> Click me! </button>` you can add a handler:

```
document.getElementById('clickme').addEventListener('click', function(){
    document.getElementByClassName('fb-page')[0].setAttribute('data-show-facepile', false)
});
```

Note that if there are more than one element of the `fb-page`-class, the element you want to change may not be the first element of the returned list.

---

With jQuery: `$('.fb-page').attr('data-show-facepile', false)`. [Docs](http://api.jquery.com/attr/). If you give the element an id, you use `$('#id')` instead.

So if you have a button: `<button id="fb-show-button">Click me! </button>` you add a handler:

```
$('#fb-show-button').click(function(){
    $('.fb-page')[0].attr('data-show-facepile', false)
})
```

The note from above also affects this example.

---

Why do I mention the use of id instead of class? Because when there's a specific element you want to handle, the ID will identify it uniquely, as only one element can have a specific id. More than one element can have the class `fb-page`. That's why the methods getting elements of a class returns an array.

Comment: Only answer to do it via vanilla JS and jQuery, not sure about using W3Schools as a reference though haha!

Comment: Hah, double checked it and updated the answer. Thanks!

Comment: That's better imo! MDN is my weapon of choice for referencing :)

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClass is not a function :(

Comment: @ZainKhan Sorry, thought I updated the answer.  Should be `document.getElementByClassName`. Fixing now =)

Comment: Sorry, should have noticed this, should be `document.getElementsByClassName('fb-page')`, even if there is only one class on the page...

Comment: No idea about Jquery. New in this game :(

Comment: @ZainKhan It's just a library that can help you with a lot of DOM-operation. It's not important for now. Added the same example with vanilla JS, and an explanation of the use of ID's over classes. Hope it helps!

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'setAttribute' of null :( :(

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: document.getElementByClassName is not a function

Comment: `getElementByClassName` returns an array of elements, not just a single element. My bad, I'm updating my answer. My bad! That my be the cause of the first error. Can't figure out that second one, though. That function has support across all major browsers, except [IE8](http://caniuse.com/#search=getElement)

Comment: I appreciate your help very much. Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to click on the div, like this:

```
 $('.fb-page').on('click', function(){
     $(this).data('show-facepile', false);
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Very simple:

1) Give your Div an ID
2)

```
function YourEvent() {
   $('IdOfYourDiv').prop('data-show-facepile', true)
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jquery.data()

```
<button>Go</button>
<div class="fb-page" data-href="https://www.facebook.com/ConnectCommunications?fref=ts" data-width="450" data-hide-cover="false" data-show-facepile="true" data-small-header="false" data-show-posts="true">Test</div>
```

jQuery:

```
alert(jQuery('.fb-page').data('show-facepile'));
jQuery('button').on('click', function(){
    jQuery('div').data('show-facepile', false);
    alert(jQuery('.fb-page').data('show-facepile'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/2taxxnwn/